# Creating a very simple IRC bot with SSL?

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, openssl

How do I implement SSL with this? I've been trying to use an SSL socket but I haven't been able to get it to work yet. Any ideas?

Thanks,
Dennis

Edit: Got it!

```
# Import some necessary libraries.
import socket, ssl

# Some basic variables used to configure the bot        
server = "irc.freenode.net" # Server
port = 7000 # Port
channel = "#test" # Channel
botnick = "LOLBOT" # Your bots nick

def ping(): # This is our first function! It will respond to server Pings.
  ircsock.send("PONG :pingis\n")  

def sendmsg(chan , msg): # This is the send message function, it simply sends messages to the channel.
  ircsock.send("PRIVMSG "+ chan +" :"+ msg +"\n") 

def joinchan(chan): # This function is used to join channels.
  ircsock.send("JOIN "+ chan +"\n")

def hello(): # This function responds to a user that inputs "Hello Mybot"
  ircsock.send("PRIVMSG "+ channel +" :Hello!\n")

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((server, port)) # Here we connect to the server using the port 6667
ircsock = ssl.wrap_socket(s)
ircsock.send("USER "+ botnick +" "+ botnick +" "+ botnick +" :This bot is a result of a tutoral covered on http://shellium.org/wiki.\n") # user authentication
ircsock.send("NICK "+ botnick +"\n") # here we actually assign the nick to the bot

joinchan(channel) # Join the channel using the functions we previously defined

while 1: # Be careful with these! it might send you to an infinite loop
  ircmsg = ircsock.recv(2048) # receive data from the server
  ircmsg = ircmsg.strip('\n\r') # removing any unnecessary linebreaks.
  print(ircmsg) # Here we print what's coming from the server

  if ircmsg.find(":Hello "+ botnick) != -1: # If we can find "Hello Mybot" it will call the function hello()
    hello()

  if ircmsg.find("PING :") != -1: # if the server pings us then we've got to respond!
    ping()
```

Comment: I noticed I've been rambling. Basically I'm failing to SSL wrap the socket. Can someone give me an example on how to do this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the danger of missing the question *entirely*, have you tried [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/supybot/)?

Comment: Yes, I have, but I rather try, understand and program a bot myself :)

Comment: A very novel approach, and I wish you the very best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

It hasn't been updated in a while, but [irclib](http://python-irclib.sourceforge.net/) supports ssl sockets.  You can take a look at how it does it.